# Moment JS not recognising ISO 8601 date

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, jsx, iso8601

So I've got two dates I'd like to get the difference of:

```
console.log(new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()); //2017-07-07T16:55:30.471Z
console.log(asset.past[i].date); //2017-07-06T20:29:00.670Z
var a = moment([new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()]);
console.log(a); //Moment Date:Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000
var b = moment([asset.past[i].date]);
console.log(b); //Moment Date:Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000
console.log(a.diff(b, 'seconds', true)); //0
console.log(a.diff(b, 'days', true)); //0
console.log(a.diff(b, 'months', true)); //0
```

I've put the out put of the console logs as comments afterwards. I assume it doesn't recognize the date format as ISO 8601 and defaults to Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000. Either way, any idea how to fix it?

Cheers, Ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you passing in an array to the moment constructor? What do you want `a` to actually be, just the current date? If so just do `moment()`. If you want to pass in a string do it like you correctly did on line 1.

Here are just the 2 fixes where I removed the square brackets. Again, you can just do `moment()` to get a moment that points to now.

```
// var a = moment(new Date(Date.now()).toISOString());
var a = moment();
var b = moment(asset.past[i].date);
```

Comment: I saw this in the docs: `var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);` and figured I should put it in an array, I am not a smart man...     Thanks mate!

Comment: @EdLynch - you can do that if you as in an array of numbers where each number represents a time segment (1st = year, 2nd = month, 3rd = day, etc).

Comment: Oh yeah I know, it just said I couldn't for 3 minutes so I figured I do it later, it let me now.

Comment: new Date() is not the same as Date.now(), one returns an object and the other a number.